# GRUB- error: no such partition grub rescue and Error: No default or UI configuration directive found  boot > on pendrive 

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, live-usb

I have dell inspiron, previously I  installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Windows 7 and made it dual boot.

But since I want to upgrade my Ubuntu version and change the partition spacing, I  deleted 11.10 partition directly and extended my hardrive space (Windows + Ubuntu) at that moment everything was fine.

Then I  prepared a 12.04 32bit USB and installed it . It was installed but isn't showing dual boot option like 11.10 and my machine directly boot into Windows 7. So instantly i again deleted my 12.04 partition .

Now I  login into Windows 7 but whenever I put USB ( with 12.04 ) to boot from it, I am facing error of "no such partition grub rescue" even though I try to put lower version(11.04) it showing another error "Error: No default or UI configuration directive found  boot >"

I have reinstall Windows 7 and reformat all partition, still I am facing same error :(

Comment: To help you it would be very helpful if we knew what partitions you have right now.  Boot off the LiveUSB and when you get to the desktop open a terminal window and type the command: "sudo fdisk -l" and paste the results into your question here.

Comment: @fabricator4 he can't boot from Live USB

Comment: @fabricator4 i tried do this before but it says no command

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your USB in the port, boot from it.
2. When it displays `Error: No default or UI configuration directive found` , press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key twice quickly. This will show you the available options. such as `live`, `local` etc
3. Type `live` and Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter to the Live Session.
4. Then install Ubuntu from there.

   - [Install Ubuntu & Win7 side by side](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26264/install-ubuntu-win7-side-by-side)

Comment: i will try it but i don't understand why two diffrent error for diffrent versions

Comment: i have try this but no change as expected live ,local. :( it showing "no configuration file found" before then "No default or UI configuration directive found" then "boot :". and one more question why it is showing two diffrent error for two diffrent versions... please help....

Comment: guys please help me :(

Comment: type `live` at the `boot:` prompt and hit Enter.